# passing a variable as an argument in containable function

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am looking for some possiblility to pass a paramter in contain's function

```
$query = $products->find()->contain([
    'Categories' => function ($q) {
       return $q->where(['Categories.category_id' => $categoryId]);
    }
]);
```

in this case I want to pass `$categoryId` as argument.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and

Comment: ```function ($q) use ($categoryId) { ...```

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#filtering-by-associated-data

check this 
, function ($q) use ($categoryId) {
    return $q->where(['Categories.category_id' => $categoryId]